# Harden sshd_config via python

Tags: python, python-3.x

1. Find line starting with "#PermitRootLogin yes" and replace with "PermitRootLogin no"
2. Append line at the bottom saying "AllowUsers user1@test.com"
3. Restart sshd daemon

(My Code)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("/etc/ssh/sshd_config", inplace=True), : 
    print (line.replace("#PermitRootLogin", "PermitRootLogin no"))
```

(Error)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./assignment4-part1.py", line 6, in 
    print (line.replace("#PermitRootLogin", "PermitRootLogin=no"))
AttributeError: 'FileInput' object has no attribute 'replace'

(Notes)

I tried different methods as seen from other posts doing find and replace line, but run into similar problems/errors.  Any guidance would be much appreciated.  I am using CentOS, and python3 is installed/updated.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your code.  Your `for` loop expression has an erroneous comma:

```
for line in fileinput.input("/etc/ssh/sshd_config", inplace=True), :
```

That means that you're actually iterating over a single-element tuple, containing a `fileinput.FileInput` object, rather than iterating over the object itself.

Remove the comma:

```
for line in fileinput.input("sshd_config", inplace=True):
```

Two other short recommendations:

Don't use `print` in your loop, because `print` appends a newline, so you'll end up double-spacing your entire file.  Consider instead:

```
for line in fileinput.input("sshd_config", inplace=True):                       
    sys.stdout.write(line.replace("#PermitRootLogin", "PermitRootLogin no"))
```

Lastly, consider what will happen if your input file contains:

```
#PermitRootLogin no
```

Your code will rewrite this as:

```
PermitRootLogin no no
```

Which is invalid.

Comment: thanks for the help.  still ran into some problems.  if I put my sshd_config file in the same folder as my script, when I run it, it erases everything in the file, and it gives me below error.

Comment: thanks for the help. still ran into some problems. if I put my sshd_config file in the same folder as my script, when I run it, it erases everything in the file, and it gives me below error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssh-part1.py", line 6, in <module>
    sys.stdout.write(line.replace("#PermitRootLogin", "PermitRootLogin no"))
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined

Comment: Use import sys before using sys. For more details on sys module. Refer below link:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html (python 2) and https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html (python 3)

Comment: @larsks, yes print appends a newline. This happens because "_print_" in python contains "_end_" parameter whose default value is "\n" (_newline_). So if you want to use "_print_" in this case, use by initializing "_end_" parameter as blank " ". Eg: **print(line.replace("#PermitRootLogin", "PermitRootLogin no"), end='')**. This will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Add `import sys` to the top if the Python file. And get a good beginners guide to Python :>

Or consider using GNU sed regex and avoid Python altogether